# ¿Cómo puedo activar varias hojas en Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Mi problema es que no puedo **activar más hojas** en **google apps script**, intento hacer un sistema Automático, que detecte hojas por su nombre, y aplicar un codigo a las seleccionadas, he utilizado getSheetByName, activate(), getActiveSheet(), pero solo me deja traer de hoja por hoja, seria de mucha ayuda que me pudieran ayudar.
**Gracias**

```
function insertTitle(){
  var ssa =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojas = ['Comisiones','Comisiones-2'];
  var hojasAct = "";
    
  for(var z = 0; z < 2; z++){
    hojasAct = hojas[z];
    var sheet = ssa.getSheetByName(hojasAct);
    sheet.activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: La pregunta es es sobre un Problema XY. No es posible activar varias hojas de manera simultánea, pero eso en realidad es irrelevante. ¿Para qué crees que necesitas activar las hojas?

Comment: Lo que realmente, necesitaba era poder activar un arreglo con nombres de hojas

Comment: Así podría aplicar un código a direferentes  hojas (personalizadas )  del documento

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con con "activar un arreglo con nombres de hojas"? ¿quieres decir leer? ¿quizás declarar?

Answer (score 0):

Para declarar un objeto de tipo Array de objetos de Class Sheet a partir de un Array de nombres de hojas puedes usar lo siguiente

```
const nombres = ['hoja 1','hoja 2'];
const hojas = nombres.map((nombre) => SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(nombre));
```

Lo anterior requiere del uso del nuevo tiempo de ejecución .